# Best API for token data on Binance Smart Chain?

Tags: blockchain, bsc, external-api

I'm currently putting together a project and I need to pull token data from an API. Now of course I've done research but it seems that there's a variety of them to choose from. At a minimum, I need the api to give me the price of a token and if applicable, the total number of wallets holding said token. If there's anyone here that has much more experience in this than myself, I would greatly appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [CoinBrain](https://coinbrain.com) API for obtaining price and market cap and it serves me well so far. Definitely can recommend. I'm not sure if they provide also the wallet holdings but you can check with them.

Good thing is that the API is for free and very fast. So far I haven't run on any problem...